# Why use the action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Customize the action bar is not very easy, and if you support the old android versions you need the compatibility library. What are the advantages and disadvantages to use a view instead of the action bar?

Comment: what view are you talking about ?

Comment: You might ask why use the window controls (close, minimize, etc) on Windows? Why not create your own window control widgets? Its usability.

Comment: @pskink A view element (<View/>) for simulate the action bar.

Comment: @brummfondel the action bar have no the window controls, only the title and few buttons.

Comment: @user3807622 please read my complete answer not only the last part.

Comment: It is all about creating a user experience that feels natural accross all android applications. If everyone made their own view it would start to create either a headache or an eyesore (or both) for users and developers alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action bar is an important design element, usually at the top of each screen in an app, that provides a `consistent familiar look` between Android apps. It is used to provide better `user interaction` and experience by supporting `easy navigation` through tabs and drop-down lists. It also provides a `space for the app or activity’s identity`, thus enabling the user to know their location in the app, and `easy access` to the actions that can be performed.

Comment: Thanks for replace. Yes, I know, but my question is what is the difference between an action bar and a view that simulate it?

Comment: this is the difference over it

Comment: @user3807622 he is saying it provides a means of labeling the application and accessing a menu that universal accross android. Providing your own view and may appear the same, but it will have noticeable differences that may make the user experience lest fluid and comfortable

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you've made a view that works the same and look the same as the action bar, you've actually implemented the action bar, so why bother doing it instead of just taking the code of it...

Anyway, the action bar is a very well known component over most Android apps, and it's part of the look&feel of them and of the OS itself.

doing things on your own will take a lot of time and effort, and it will have a huge chance of making the users not comfortable with using it (unless you've done something really remarkable and easy to use).

developers can always "invent the wheel" , but most of the times, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

use `ActionBar` instead of a `View` so you won't reinvent the wheel. It's not hard to customize if you use tools: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/